# How to make git to authenticate with correct username via SSH?

Tags: git, ssh

I work with `git` on Windows and can't make it to authenticate with correct username, different from the one I'm logged in to local OS.

Here are the details.

An upstream repository is located on a remote machine which I want to connect to via SSH:

```bash
$ git remote -v
origin    ssh://someuser@host/path (fetch)
origin    ssh://someuser@host/path (push)
```

I use an SSH key for authentication.

Running just an `ssh` command works fine:

```
$ ssh someuser@host "whoami"
someuser
```

But when trying to push changes to the repository I get prompted for password under username of **local OS user, not the user specified in remote path**:

```
$ git push
(OSuser@host) Password for OSuser@host:
```

I have configured `user.name`:

```
$ git config user.name
someuser
```

But it has no effect.

I tried running `git pull` both from `git-bash` shell and Windows' `cmd`. Result is the same.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Everyone please say it with me now: `user.name` has **nothing** to do with authentication. It's **only** there to indicate a commit's author. (Same with `user.email`.)

What do you get if you run `GIT_SSH_CMD="ssh -v" git push`?

Comment: @JimRedmond, the issue was in my default SSH command: it had an explicit username. Thank you for turning my attention to it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I've altered a default SSH command, explicitly specifying a username there, and then forgot about it:

```
$ git config core.sshCommand
ssh -l OSuser
```

That is why username from remote path was overriden by username from the command.

Thanks to **Jim Redmond**, who turned my attention to that area.